# SQL IN Operator in nested queries

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I have a single table named "Employees" where the column "Email" refers to the employee's email and the column "MgrEmail" refers to their direct manager's email.

I created a query that should find all of the third level employees  in the management hierarchy. however, it doesn't retrieve the correct records I'm not sure why.

```
 SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE MgrEmail IN
    (SELECT Email
     FROM Employees
     WHERE MgrEmail IN
         (SELECT Email
          FROM Employees
          WHERE MgrEmail='test@test.com'))
```

Comment: Kindly share sample data in text format and your desired result

Comment: Add aliases to the table expressions and use prefixes to show the DB Engine which instance of the table you want it to query.

Comment: what is table `sap`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the marker for a manager is his manager email is `NULL`, then one option would be to just do two self joins of the `Employees` table, starting with the third level employees, and stopping when we find a manager two steps higher.

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM Employees e1
INNER JOIN Employees e2
    ON e1.MgrEmail = e2.Email
INNER JOIN Employees e3
    ON e2.MgrEmail = e3.Email
WHERE e3.MgrEmail IS NULL      -- assuming that a manager would himself have no manager
```